# (Bootstrap 5) Col elements not inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to implement a col with 3 elements inline : 2 buttons and one select

I managed to get it to work with three buttons, but if I remove a button and add a select for some unknown reason it doesn't work.

3 buttons working and properly aligned:

[image]

If we click on Tab2, all three items appear messed up:

[image]

What I've tried so far:

I thought it was a `form-select` width problem, it was set to `100%` so I did:

```
.form-select {
    width: unset;
}
```

But still the three elements are misaligned and not inline.

[image]

How can I get those three elements inline?

[LIVE JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gerasg/7wtzo4xL/64/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your select keeps going to the next line is because the `.form-select` class by default has a display type of `block`

To fix your problem, you are correct in thinking that you should use `width: unset`, however you must also set `display: inline-block` to prevent it from going to the next line.

The following CSS should be added:

```css
.form-select {
  width: unset; /* note: width: auto; would also work here */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/bem0ojry/

Note that this will only make the 3 elements side by side if there is enough space, otherwise they will automatically wrap to the next line.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: Excellent, thank you!